# IOS Crashing with MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.6 and SFMCSDK1.0.4

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I'm working with the latest version of marketingcloudsdk 8.0.6. I followed the documentation correctly, after some issues the push notification is arriving on the devices.
There is sometimes a crash in the application startup that I could not identify. here are some logs:
Ios Versions 13,14 and 15 are affected.

```
2022-07-05 18:11:48.028085-0300 Catho[26130:972784] [sdk] New operation (1 of 100) added to the sfmcsdk.eventbus.push queue.
["MKT CLOUD SDK is SUCCESS"]
2022-07-05 18:11:48.028248-0300 Catho[26130:972711] [module] log: `sfmc_setContactKey ******** succeeded` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m` line: `line: 40`
2022-07-05 18:11:48.028204-0300 Catho[26130:972739] [module] log: `network request SFMCNetworkRequest` file: `MarketingCloudSDKControlChannel.m` line: `line: 231`
2022-07-05 18:11:48.028461-0300 Catho[26130:972757] [module] log: `registration key path observer for blob` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 660`
2022-07-05 18:11:48.028668-0300 Catho[26130:972757] [module] log: `sfmc_setAttributeNamed key: usr_id, value: ******** succeeded, attributes now {
    "usr_id" = ********;
}` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m` line: `line: 361`
2022-07-05 18:11:48.028782-0300 Catho[26130:972757] [module] log: `sfmc_attributes getter returning {
    "usr_id" = ********;
}` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m` line: `line: 437`
2022-07-05 18:11:48.028790-0300 Catho[26130:972711] [eventBus] Message `IdentityEvent` received on the event bus.
2022-07-05 18:11:48.028924-0300 Catho[26130:972757] [eventBus] Message `IdentityEvent` received on the event bus.
2022-07-05 18:11:48.029541-030["home"]2022-07-05 18:11:48.029579-0300 Catho[26130:972711] [eventBus] Message `IdentityEvent` send to `push`

0 Catho[26130:972757] [eventBus] Message `IdentityEvent` send to `push`
2022-07-05 18:11:48.040892-0300 Catho[26130:972711] [sdk] New operation (2 of 100) added to the sfmcsdk.eventbus.push queue.
2022-07-05 18:11:48.040899-0300 Catho[26130:972757] [sdk] New operation (2 of 100) added to the sfmcsdk.eventbus.push queue.
```

And the crash is :

**#0  0x000000010481cf05 in swift_isUniquelyReferenced_nonNull_native ()
Thread 2: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)**

or sometimes

```
2022-07-05 18:46:23.561889-0300 Catho[27951:1018096] [sdk] New operation (2 of 100) added to the sfmcsdk.eventbus.push queue.
2022-07-05 18:46:23.561903-0300 Catho[27951:1018074] [sdk] New operation (2 of 100) added to the sfmcsdk.eventbus.push queue.
2022-07-05 18:46:23.562079-0300 Catho[27951:1018088] [event] Dropping self-produced event with id `EB1E1255-E1B0-4D2E-AAFE-27E5DAD856A0` and name `IdentityEvent`
```

And the crash is :

**Thread 12 Queue : sfmcsdk.eventbus.push (QOS: UNSPECIFIED) (concurrent)**

We had to remove the sdk and release another version of the app into production as we couldn't understand how to handle this crash.
Can anyone help?